# How is GNU Classpath related to libgcj?

Tags: gnu-classpath, libgcj

Both projects are free implementations of the Java standard libraries. libgcj's homepage says it was merged with Classpath, but they're still separate packages in Ubuntu.

So what's the difference? Is one better than the other? Does one depend on the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Classpath is a reimplementation of Sun's built-in Java classes. libgcj is a native library used for running Java apps compiled to native code via gcj. They're under the same umbrella, but have different purposes.

Comment: So for example, if you were writing your own JVM you could've Classpath as your standard library, and if you just wanted to build a native Java app, you would use libgcj? Do they share any code?

Comment: *You* would not have to use libgcj (rather, gcj would link against it), but otherwise correct. They are in different languages, and so share little if any code.